# Service broker inside a trigger calling linked server stored procedure with queued data as parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-trigger, service-broker

Due to the companies policy and especially db admins suggestions I am not able to use trigger calling any complex logic (in the case of mine, calling a linked server stored procedure).

I was suggested to implement service broker architecture instead, so my question is if this is even possible and how can I combine it with the logic below,
Storing data in a queue and passing it into the stored procedure.

I may be missing some common sense here but that is due to my lack of understanding for service broker and time for completion.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[BenRef_UPDATEtrg]
   ON [dbo].[ITRAEN]
 AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

 BEGIN

   IF UPDATE(poz2) 

    BEGIN 


 DECLARE @benRefNum VARCHAR(30);
 DECLARE @partija VARCHAR(30);
 DECLARE @unikum VARCHAR(30);



    DECLARE @storeBenRef as table
    (
        BeneficiaryRef VARCHAR(30), 
        Partija VARCHAR(30) collate Serbian_Latin_100_CI_AS, 
        Datum DATETIME,
        Unikum VARCHAR(30)
    )


-- Trigger logic
INSERT INTO @storeBenRef ( BeneficiaryRef, Partija, Datum, Unikum) 
  SELECT i.poz2, i.PARTIJA,CONVERT(DATETIME,i.DOTVORANJE,121) AS datum,i.Unikum
       FROM inserted i
         INNER JOIN deleted d 
             ON i.PARTIJA = d.PARTIJA


    SET @benRefNum = ( SELECT BeneficiaryRef FROM @storeBenRef);
    SET @partija = ( SELECT partija FROM @storeBenRef);
    SET @unikum = (SELECT Unikum FROM @storeBenRef);


     /*
   Linked server procedure using retrieved data as parameters 
     */

    EXEC [EXPSRV1].[OPR].[dbo].[BenRefUpdate] @BenRefNum = @benRefNum, @Party = @partija,@Arrangement_unikum = @unikum;


END
```

Comment: It is possible, yes, but a bit broad to demonstrate in this space. Instead of typing out what has been typed out already, I'll leave you with this introductory link: [SQL Server Service Broker example on how to configure, send and receive messages](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1836/sql-server-service-broker-example-on-how-to-configure-send-and-receive-messages/).

Comment: It looks like in this case, you'd create a message with the parameters to the `[dbo].[BenRefUpdate]` stored procedure and send it to a queue in the `[OPR]` database. There would be a stored procedure there that, when there are messages to be processed on the queue, would pull that message off of the queue and run the stored procedure.